# Does java Date handles localization(one of the reason to choose Calendar over Date)?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I always preferto use calendar over date class as its robust on date manipulation(Also i read somewhere Date class mainly exist becoz of backward compatibility probably for prior to jdk 1.1).But i think today i have got one more reason to go with calendar i.e calendar handles the localization which means that when i do

> Calendar.getInstance()

it will return the calendar object depending  on timezone and locale of box where code is deployed. But when i do

> new Date()

it will return the date object in respect to GMT(thats the feeling i got after going thru http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date())

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Date represents an instant in time, and doesn't care about the time zone and locale. You only care about time zone and locale when you want to parse or format a date for a human (using SimpleDateFormat), or when you start comparing the date with some wall-clock value, wondering if the date is within a given month, day or hour, or adding days and taking daylight savings into account (and in this case you transform the date into a Calendar).

So Date isn't inherently a less useful class than Calendar. It just doesn't serve the same purpose. Both are complementary.

I would recommend using joda-time anyway, which is a much better API, but still has the same concepts of an instant, and of a zoned date time.

Comment: As you said "A Date represents an instant in time, and doesn't care about the time zone and locale". My question here is if i do new Date() on two different boxes say in US and Germany, will it return the same value. If yes, does it mean that value will represent the instant in time  with respect to some standard time like GMT

Comment: If you're interested in Joda, take a look at https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp which is a java 7 implementation of the new date API coming in java 8

Comment: so if i do date.getDay() on machhine in dubai and it returns int representing Monday. then its not necessarly monday in dubai but if i do Calndar.DAY_OF_WEEK  it will for sure return monday. Right?

Comment: If two programs executing in two different places in the world execute new Date() at the same time, they will both get the same value. This value is the number of milliseconds that elapsed since the moment represented as the 1st January 1970 00:00 UTC.

Comment: You should never call date.getDay(), because it's deprecated. It returns the day that this date is on in the current time zone. Getting the day from a Calendar object will return the day this date is on in the time zone of the Calendar object (chosen at construction time).

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` object internally stores the date as a number of miliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC. However when you are accessing for example the hour represented by a `Date` object it DOES consider timezone information. This can be verified using this simple code:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(1368868487441L);

        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Now if you run it setting the timezone (as a JVM startup parameter) to `-Duser.timezone="Europe/Sofia"` you get

```
Sat May 18 12:14:47 EEST 2013
```

but if you change it to `-Duser.timezone="America/Arizona"` the result is different

```
Sat May 18 09:14:47 GMT 2013
```

This is because `Date` actually uses a `Calendar` instance internally to convert from
the number of milis since "the Epoch" to the actual time values.